# My program has a warning while using fgets

Tags: c, data-structures

I just study about data structure and i have a task to make a program that can make a report and save it on a file. My program works fine but it has some warning.

1. passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type
2. comparison between pointer and integer

```
void order(){
    int i = 1, j = 0, x;
    int jmlh;
    char namaKasir[101];
    dM a[100];
    system("cls");
    FILE *menu, *harga, *jenis, *report, *report2;
    report2 = fopen("Report.txt","a");
    report = fopen("Report2.txt","r");
    jenis = fopen("Type.txt","r");
    menu = fopen("Nama.txt","r");
    harga = fopen("Price.txt","r");
    
    if(menu == NULL && jenis == NULL && harga == NULL){
        printf("Tidak ada menu\n\n");
    }
    
    printf("Pilih Menu :\n");
    while(fgets(&a[j].nM,100,menu)!=EOF&&fgets(&a[j].jenis,100,jenis)!=EOF&&fscanf(harga,"%d",&a[j].harga)!=EOF){
        printf("%d.%s",i,a[j].nM);
        printf("Rp.%d\n",a[j].harga);
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    
    scanf("%d",&x); fflush(stdin);
    puts("Masukkan Jumlah: ");
    scanf("%d",&jmlh); fflush(stdin);
    puts("Masukkan Nama Kasir: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",namaKasir); fflush(stdin);
    time_t waktu = time(NULL);
    char * waktu_arr = ctime(&waktu);
    x -= 1;
    printf("\nPesanan berhasil diinput.\n\n");//printing order to report.txt
    fprintf(report2,"Waktu Pemesanan: %s", waktu_arr);
    fprintf(report2,"Nama Kasir: %s\n",namaKasir);
    fprintf(report2,"Nama Pesanan: %s",a[x].nM);
    fprintf(report2,"Jenis Pesanan: %s",a[x].jenis);
    fprintf(report2,"Jumlah Pesanan: %d\n",jmlh);
    fprintf(report2,"Subtotal: %d\n\n",a[x].harga*jmlh);
    
    fclose(report);
    fclose(report2);
    fclose(jenis);
    fclose(menu);
    fclose(harga);
}
```

in this program i am using a data structure

```
typedef struct dataMenu{
    char nK[100]; //nama kasir
    char nM[100]; //nama makanan
    char jenis[100]; //jenis makanan
    int jumlah; //jumlah makanan
    int harga;  //harga makanan
    int total;  //total harga makanan
}dM;
```

The warning is for this code

```
while(fgets(&a[j].nM,100,menu)!=EOF&&fgets(&a[j].jenis,100,jenis)!=EOF&&fscanf(harga,"%d",&a[j].harga)!=EOF){
        printf("%d.%s",i,a[j].nM);
        printf("Rp.%d\n",a[j].harga);
        j++;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: `&a[j].nM` is not a `char*`, it's a pointer to a `char[100]` - not the same thing. Just use `a[j].nM` and it'll decay into a `char*`

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`, or you might be using uninitialized variables if the input is malformed. And add some padding spaces, that `while` conditional is bloody hard to decipher.

Comment: `a[j].xx`  are already char arrays, so they will decay to pointers. You should just remove the offending `&`, and compare the result value from `fgets` to `NULL`: `while(fgets(a[j].nM,100,menu)!=NULL...`

Comment: @Serge Note that `fgets` doesn't return an `int` error code - it returns a `char*`, which is `NULL` on failure.

Comment: @Ted - See my previous comment.

Comment: ... and the chances of it ever actually returning `EOF` (typically, -1) are remote indeed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i tried your advice and it works thank you

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you my program now works without warning

Comment: You should also get used to check the amount of successfully scanned elements returned from  the `scanf` family of functions. Instead of `!= EOF` put the actual number of elements you expect to extract from the stream, like `fscanf(harga, "%d", &a[j].harga) == 1` etc.

Comment: @Alvin: Congrats should go to AdrianMole: **he** gave me  the correct answer for the `EOF` part...

Comment: @Serge I accept all major credit cards, gold bullion, and even "green tick marks". :-)

Comment: @Adrian: sorry I cannot access the *green tick mark*... But I have already sent a *up triangle* and I wish you a happy new year!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems in a single line of your code:

```c
while(fgets(&a[j].nM,100,menu)!=EOF&&fgets(&a[j].jenis,100,jenis)!=EOF&&fscanf(harga,"%d",&a[j].harga)!=EOF){
```

First, your `.nm` and `.jenis` members are arrays of `char`, so they automatically 'decay' into pointers when used as arguments in functions calls; so, you shouldn't add the `&` operator on those arguments.

Second, the [`fgets()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) returns a `char*` argument – which will be the passed string, on success, and `NULL` on failure; so, you should check for the calls not returning `NULL`, rather than not returning `EOF` (which they almost certainly *never* will, unless the address of the given string encodes as a pointer equivalent of `-1`).

Third, the [`fscanf()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns the number of values successfully read, or `0` if none can be; so, you should compare the return value of that call to `1`, to spot errors in the integer conversion.

So, here's that line with the corrections I suggested made:

```c
while (fgets(a[j].nM, 100, menu) != NULL && fgets(a[j].jenis, 100, jenis) != NULL && fscanf(harga, "%d", &a[j].harga) == 1) {
```